# Program that hosts every string one writes in the shell to the ip url using wsgi (and only the wsgiref module)

Tags: python, hosting, cgi, wsgi

I want to make a small program with wsgi that allows me to type strings in my shell and output it on my ip url.

Currently I have this `wsgi_app.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return [cont]

while True:
    cont = raw_input(">>>")
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

This outputs `>>>` in my shell, and I can then type in a string. If I go to `192.xxx.x.xx:8080` I can see what I wrote. The problem is that this only works one time, I would like the `raw_input()` to loop so I can type in new strings, than refresh the webpage and see the new content. My guess is that `serve_forever()` is already an infinite loop and that makes sure the body of my while loop never reaches an end. Is there another way using only the wsgiref module to keep on outputting `>>>` after each input and hosting my input on my webpage (in other words, to end the body of my while loop with some other function in wsgiref)?

Extra question: Is it possible to make my webpage autorefresh, so I don't have to manually refresh in my browser each time to see the new strings I wrote?

---

**Improved, version 1.1**

Using `server.handle_request()` instead of `server.serve_forever()`, this baby can finally loop. This version prints out new input you type in the shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return [cont]

i = 1

while True:
    cont = raw_input(">>> ")
    if i == 1:
        server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
    server.handle_request()
    i += 1
```

---

Version 1.1 does however not display the previously inputted text. So now in **version 1.2** I am using a list to store the previously inputted text. *Unfortunately this code doesn't display text when I enter a text for the second time. Does anyone know why?*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return [str(cont())]

def cont():
    for k in l:
        return k + '\n'

i = 1
l = []

while True:
    l.append(raw_input(">>> "))
    if i == 1:
        server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
    server.handle_request()
    i += 1
```

Comment: You will need to open a `socket` to do this.

Comment: Check out this post on using WebSockets to send intermittent data: http://yz.mit.edu/wp/web-sockets-tutorial-with-simple-python-server/

Comment: It should be possible(not sure about the extra question yet), check my version 1.1 in the updated original post. Do you know why my second version doesn't work properly?